# Indent all but first line of text in Bibliography section

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, indentation

I am writing a review in Latex and I'm writing the references directly into the Bibliography section in the main.tex file without using BibTex or bibitems or anything like that. I want to indent all but the first line for each reference. I've tried all the techniques to do this for normal text like using `\parindent` but it never works on the text directly written in the Bibliography section.

I want it to look like this:
[image]

This is what I have right now:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{} \normalsize

Adams, F. C., Batygin, K., Bloch, A. M., \& Laughlin, G. (2020). Energy optimization in extrasolar planetary 
systems:The transition from peas-in-a-pod to runaway growth. Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society,
493(4), 5520–5531. https://doi.org/10.1093/mnras/staa624\\[2mm]

Adams, E. R., Seager, S.,\& Elkins-Tanton, L. (2008). Ocean planet or thick atmosphere: On the mass-radius 
relationship for solid exoplanets with massive atmospheres. The Astrophysical Journal, 673, 1160–1164. 
https://doi.org/10.1086/524925\\[2mm]

ALMA Partnership, Brogan, C. L., Pérez, L. M., Hunter, T. R., Dent, W. R. F., Hales, A. S., et al. (2015). 
The 2014 ALMA long baseline campaign: First results from high angular resolution observations toward the HL 
Tau region. The Astrophysical Journal Letters, 808(1), L3. https://doi.org/10.1088/2041-8205/808/1/L3\\[2mm]
```

I know this is not very practical and not the proper way but I do not have time to learn how to do it properly.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome! Please complete your code so we can compile a small example which reproduces the problem. Why use `thebibliography` environment at all if you're just typing them all by hand anyway? `\bibitem` is basically just a tailored version of `\item`. It would take less than 5 minutes to learn to use it.

Comment: I know how to use `\bibitem` to reference in IEEE style which uses numbers, but I am unsure of how to use `\bibitem` to reference in the Harvard way without numbers on the side

Comment: I think you would put whatever you want to be the label into the optional argument. I'm not clear what `thebibliography` environment will do for you otherwise, so if you can't get it to work like that, you might just not use the environment. If it isn't helping with the formatting, it's not really doing anything useful.

Comment: Don't use `\\` to end a line unless you're in `tabular` or similar. It will fill your log with warnings because TeX won't be able to break the text properly.

Comment: The `hanging` package provides functions for typing any sort of "hanging" paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage[authoryear,round,compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike} 

\begin{document}

... \citep{adams-etal:2020,adams-etal:2008,alma-etal:2015}
\begin{thebibliography}{999} 
\normalsize

\bibitem[Adams et al.(2020)]{adams-etal:2020} Adams, F. C., Batygin, K., Bloch, A. M., \& Laughlin, G. (2020). 
Energy optimization in extrasolar planetary systems: The transition from peas-in-a-pod to runaway growth. 
\emph{Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society},
\emph{493}(4), 5520--5531. 
\url{https://doi.org/10.1093/mnras/staa624}

\bibitem[Adams et al.(2008)]{adams-etal:2008}Adams, E. R., Seager, S., \& Elkins-Tanton, L. (2008). 
Ocean planet or thick atmosphere: On the mass-radius  relationship for solid exoplanets with massive atmospheres. 
\emph{The Astrophysical Journal}, \emph{673}, 1160--1164. 
\url{https://doi.org/10.1086/524925}

\bibitem[ALMA Parternership et al.(2015)]{alma-etal:2015}ALMA Partnership, Brogan, C. L., Pérez, L. M., Hunter, T. R., Dent, W. R. F., Hales, A. S., et al. (2015). 
The 2014 ALMA long baseline campaign: First results from high angular resolution observations toward the HL Tau region. 
\emph{The Astrophysical Journal Letters}, \emph{808}(1), L3. 
\url{https://doi.org/10.1088/2041-8205/808/1/L3}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That solves my problem! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Do you also know how to only make the year a hyperlink when citing references in the text?

Comment: @Violet - Please see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27311/5001) by [@Audrey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4483/audrey) to the query [How to hyperlink only the year part when using natbib and hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23227/5001). Be sure to copy and paste roughly 25 lines of code of @Audrey's answer -- from `\usepackage{etoolbox}` to `\makeatother` from that answer -- into the preamble of your LaTeX document, *after* (of course) loading `hyperref` and `natbib`.