# deeplink bibliography items using Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [biblatex: Make title hyperlink to doi url (if available)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23832/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-doi-url-if-available)

I am looking for a way to make my bibliography items links to the articles on the internet using Biblatex.

The input for this link should be the `OPTurl = {},` in Bibtex entry.

As a side question, is there a way to do this using Biblatex-Chicago?

Comment: You should have a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23832/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-doi-url-if-available?rq=1) and [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/hyperlink-name-with-biblatex-authoryear/25972#25972).

Comment: thank you that was very helpful, the eventual answer I found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48400/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-dois-url-or-isbn