# Colored Hyperlink in beamer

Tags: beamer, hyperref, color

I wanted to have coloured citation in beamer. I have used the following code,

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
    \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{bm}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{color}
    %\usepackage{multimedia}
    %\usepackage{movie15}
    %\usepackage{tikz}
    %\tikzset{
    %  every overlay node/.style={
    %    draw=black,anchor=north west,
    %  },
    %}
    %\def\tikzoverlay{%
    %   \tikz[baseline,overlay]\node[every overlay node]
    %}%

    %%for Justifying in itemised 

    \usepackage{ragged2e}

    \let\olditem=\item% 
    \renewcommand{\item}{\olditem \justifying}%
    %--------------------------------------------------
    %for objective theorm enviroment

    \makeatletter
    \def\th@mystyle{%
        \normalfont % body font
        \setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=red!80,fg=white}
        \setbeamercolor{block body example}{bg=red!20,fg=black}
        \def\inserttheoremblockenv{exampleblock}
      }
    \makeatother
    \theoremstyle{mystyle}
    \newtheorem*{Objective}{Objective}

    %%-------------------------


    \usepackage{csquotes}% Recommended


    \usepackage[backend=biber,
      style=authoryear,
       ]{biblatex}
    \DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

    \addbibresource{DP.bib}

    \makeatletter
    \let\abx@macro@citeOrig\abx@macro@cite
    \renewbibmacro{cite}{%
       \bibhyperref{%
       \let\bibhyperref\relax\relax%
       \abx@macro@citeOrig%
       }%
    }
    \let\abx@macro@parenciteOrig\abx@macro@parencite
    \renewbibmacro{parencite}{%
       \bibhyperref{%
       \let\bibhyperref\relax\relax%
       \abx@macro@parenciteOrig%
       }%
    }%
    \let\abx@macro@textciteOrig\abx@macro@textcite
    \renewbibmacro{textcite}{%
       \bibhyperref{%
       \let\bibhyperref\relax\relax%
       \abx@macro@textciteOrig%
       }%
    }%
    \makeatother
    %\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=.,
    menucolor=white,
    filecolor=pink,   
    anchorcolor=yellow
    }
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Multiple Model Switching Controllers}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textcite{greytak2007exponentially} gave control scheme which switches between Manifold Convergence Controller and LQR controller for underactuated Autonomous Surface Vessel (river) with just a propeller and rudder.
        \item \textcite{hassani2012multiple} proposed multiple model adaptive controller consisting of four LQG controller. The controller switching occurs to compensate for different sea state.
        \item \textcite{brodtkorb2014dynamic} demonstrated a control scheme with four different PID and sensor based observer for switching between them. Switching logic is based on spectral analysis of motion.
        \item \textcite{hassani2013novel} simulated used Robust Multiple Model Adaptive Dynamic Positioning switching Controller designed using mixed $ \mu $ methodology for different sea state.
    \end{itemize}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The problem is the ending bracket when using `\textcite{}` is not the same colour as hyperlink. What might be the issue. I'm doing this on sharelatex.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Can you add your complete and compilable MWE, please?

Comment: @Sebastiano I did. Do i need to add bib file too ?

Comment: Can you try with `\usepackage{xcolor}` instead of `\usepackage{color}`. With Papeeria or Overleaf I have problem with your code.

Comment: `\usepackage{xcolor}` did no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25972/36296 you could use:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}% Recommended
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
   ]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\hypersetup{colorlinks,
citecolor=blue,
linkcolor=.,
menucolor=white,
filecolor=pink,   
anchorcolor=yellow
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{knuth,
  author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title        = {The {\TeX} book},
  date         = 1984,
  maintitle    = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  volume       = {A},
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  location     = {Reading, Mass.},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  sortyear     = {1984-1},
  sorttitle    = {Computers & Typesetting A},
  indexsorttitle= {The TeXbook},
  indextitle   = {\protect\TeX book, The},
  shorttitle   = {\TeX book}
}

@article{einstein,
    author = {Einstein, A.},
    title = {Die Grundlage der allgemeinen Relativitätstheorie},
    journal = {Annalen der Physik},
    volume = {354},
    number = {7},
    doi = {10.1002/andp.19163540702},
    pages = {769--822},
    year = {1916}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
 {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}%
      \printtext{ (\printfield{year}\printtext{)}}}}
 {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
  {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {}%
 \multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Multiple Model Switching Controllers}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textcite{einstein} gave control scheme which switches between Manifold Convergence Controller and LQR controller for underactuated Autonomous Surface Vessel (river) with just a propeller and rudder.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Please note that you neither need `color` nor `graphicx` with beamer, as beamer already provides this functionality.