# \textcite macro produces "Author (year)" correctly but colours first paren with hyperref

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I am using a custom `\textcite` macro that I found somewhere. It works nicely except that it makes the opening paren of "Author (year)" part of the link (also colouring it blue) which is not desired.

This is likely just a minor change to the definition of the macro, but the solution eludes me (I don't get where the opening paren is added at all).

[image]

**Opening paranthesis should not be part of link and should not be coloured.**

(M)WE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
            bibencoding=utf8,
            hyperref=true,
            natbib=true,
            minnames=1,     %% prevent truncation to year-only
            backref=true, %% TODO REMOVE before final
            bibstyle=apa,
            citestyle=authoryear,
            ]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

 \DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{textcite}}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}%
   \multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}


\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{solblue}{HTML}{268BD2}

\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
   pdfhighlight = /P,
   colorlinks=true,
   urlcolor=solblue,
   filecolor=solblue,
   linkcolor=solblue,
   citecolor=solblue,
   raiselinks=true,
   breaklinks,
   unicode
}


\begin{document}

foobar \textcite{thesis_pockrandt} foobar

\end{document}
```

bib.bib:

```
@phdthesis{thesis_pockrandt,
    author = {Christopher Maximilian Pockrandt},
    title = {{Approximate String Matching: Improving Data Structures and Algorithms}},
    year = {2019}
}
```

Comment: You are using a combination of APA style and standard `authoryear: `bibstyle=apa, citestyle=authoryear,`. That setup neither conforms to APA style (because you use a different citation style) nor is it particularly customisable (`biblatex-apa` implements APA style as closely as possible, so it is much more complex than the standard styles). If you need APA style, load only `style=apa,`. If you want generic author-year citations, it is better to just load `style=authoryear,`.

Comment: Off-topic: The option `bibencoding=utf8,` is not required with a current TeX distribution, since `biblatex` tries to guess the encoding of the TeX file and uses that for the `.bib` file as well. In most current settings both will default to UTF-8. `hyperref=true,` offers little advantage of the default setting `hyperref=auto,`. With both settings `biblatex` will produce links if and only if the `hyperref` package is loaded. The only difference is that `hyperref=true,` will issue a warning if you fail to load the `hyperref` package.

Comment: Switching to `style=authoryear` does not solve the problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't want to imply that it solves the issue immediately. I would like to know if a solution has to use the non-standard combination `bibstyle=apa, citestyle=authoryear,` or if we can use either `style=apa,` or `style=authoryear,` (and if so, which?).

Comment: Hm, something with `style=authoryear` would probably work. I have no formal requirements, but when I set this up initially `apa` looked better for the actual references section but shortened citations in the text weirdly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the discussion in the comments I will answer this question for `style=authoryear,` (or more precisely, `citestyle=authoryear,`). If you are interested in a solution for APA style (of course again only `citestyle=apa,` matters), see [BibLaTeX Colors And Links Only The Year Not The Rest Of The Citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/536353/35864).

The principle to get fuller linking is the same as in [BibLaTeX Colors And Links Only The Year Not The Rest Of The Citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/536353/35864) just adjusted to the (simpler) citation style `authoryear`.

Again, there are many alternatives to get a greater link area ([hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear (biblatex 1.4b)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864), [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1687/35864), [Biblatex, authoryear-comp, and hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27607/35864), [Inconsistent bracket color with citet and citep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425283/35864)), but I feel this one is the safest (if definitely not the shortest)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
      {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
          \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
         {\printnames{labelname}%
          \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
       \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{citeyear}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
      {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
          \usebibmacro{cite:label}}%
        \setunit{%
          \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
          \printdelim{nonameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
        \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
          {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
          {}%
        \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}}
       {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}%
     \setunit{%
       \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
       \printdelim{nameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
     \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
       {}%
     \usebibmacro{citeyear}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:shorthand}{%
  \printfield{shorthand}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:label}{%
  \iffieldundef{label}
    {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
    {\printfield{label}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \printlabeldateextra}

\definecolor{solblue}{HTML}{268BD2}

\hypersetup{
   pdfhighlight = /P,
   colorlinks=true,
   urlcolor=solblue,
   filecolor=solblue,
   linkcolor=solblue,
   citecolor=solblue,
   raiselinks=true,
   breaklinks,
   unicode,
}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
lorem \textcite{sigfridsson} ipsum

dolor \autocite{sigfridsson} sit

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Linked citations with unlinked parentheses.]

Comment: Hm, this doesn't work for me: `Warning: Macro 'cite:labeldate+extradate' undefined.` and `! Undefined control sequence.
\blx@unitpunct ...ooltrue {cbx:parens}\printdelim 
                                                  {nameyeardelim}\bibopenparen 
l.85 lorem \textcite{sigfridsson} 
                                ipsum`  Note that I am on texlive 2015 unfortunately.

Comment: @h-2 That will give you a seriously outdated version of `biblatex`. No chance of an update?

Comment: No, unfortunately my distribution (FreeBSD) doesn't ship anything newer, yet. And I can't risk changing my enter setup at this point :(

Comment: @h-2 https://gist.github.com/moewew/e0e87aab0437a225cc2741c1b1ab8ee7 should work for old `biblatex` versions (I aimed for a `biblatex` version released in 2015).

Comment: That works great! Except that now the regular `\cite` is changed to `author year` instead of `author, year`. The same for `\parencite` which also now lacks the comma. And my custom `\titlecite` now includes single-quotes in the title name for some reason.

Comment: @h-2 The comma in "author year" is gone because I dropped the `natbib` option. You can get it back by adding `natbib=true,` back in or with `\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}` (actually, in your outdated version that would have to be `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\spac}`). You get single quotes because I load `babel` with the `british` option (as a global option). If you use `american` or `english` instead, you get double quotes (you can also select one of the other languages supported by `csquotes` to get typographically correct quotation marks for that locale.)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts moewe! Unfortunately your solution does not work for the style `authoryear-comp` due to _Error: Too deeply nested parentheses or brackets._
Unfortunately [this solution you've linked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27615/106142) for `authoryear-comp` does not work either for a current release (see my comment there). Is there any chance you could help? Thanks!