# \citet is not working using biblatex with natbib=true

Tags: biblatex, citing, natbib, sentence

I am writing my PhD dissertation, and I am trying to cite a reference as part of the sentence in such a way that the last name of author is followed by the year in parenthesis:

for single author

```
Author (year)
```

or for two authors

```
Author1 and Author2 (year)
```

or for more than two authors

```
Author et al. (year)
```

I tried to use `\citet` and it does not work with even using natbib. I get the following error

`Package etoolbox Error: Boolean '\ifcbx:np' undefined.`

I am using the package biblatex with natbib as follows:

```
\usepackage[
  style=authoryear,
  natbib=true,
  backend=biber,
  dashed=false,
  isbn = false,
  doi = false,
  url = false,
  language=auto,
  sorting=nyt,  
  maxbibnames=99,
  maxcitenames=2,
  uniquelist=false,
  uniquename=false]{biblatex}
```

The following are the packages I am using

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false,english,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
```

An example I have now

```
 For the former, \cite{basu2017} invoked the notion of a metric..
```

Output:

```
Basu et al., 2017
```

Desired Output:

```
Basu et al. (2017)
```

I figured the error was coming from using this macro to link both author and year

```
% long syntax to link both author & year in in-text citation
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}{}
    {\clearfield{labelmonth}% don't want months in citations
     \clearfield{labelday}% don't want days in citations
     \clearfield{labelendmonth}% don't want months in citations
     \clearfield{labelendday}% don't want days in citations
     \iffieldsequal{labelyear}{labelendyear}% Don't want no-op year ranges
       {\clearfield{labelendyear}}
       {}%
     \iffieldundef{origyear}
       {}
       {\printorigdate%
        \setunit*{\addslash}}%
     \iffieldundef{related}
       {}
       {\iffieldequalstr{relatedtype}{reprintfrom}
         {\entrydata*{\thefield{related}}{\printlabeldateextra}%
          \setunit*{\addslash}}
         {}}%
     \printlabeldateextra}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}
   {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}}%
   {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:noname}%
         \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
         \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}%
         \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}
       {\ifnameundef{shortauthor}
         {\printnames{labelname}}%
         {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
           {\printnames{shortauthor}}
           {\ifnameundef{groupauthor}
             {\printnames[labelname]{author}}
             {\printnames[labelname]{groupauthor}}%
            \addspace\printnames[sabrackets]{shortauthor}}}%
         \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}%
        \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}}%
   \setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
     \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}}
    {%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
      \setunit{\compcitedelim}%
      \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
         {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
            \usebibmacro{cite:noname}}%
          \setunit{\ifbool{cbx:np}%
                   {\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
                   {\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}\addspace\bibopenparen}}%
          \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
            \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}}
         {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
            \usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}
       {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
          \ifnameundef{shortauthor}%
           {\printnames{labelname}}
           {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
             {\printnames{shortauthor}}
             {\ifnameundef{groupauthor}
               {\printnames[labelname]{author}}
               {\printnames[labelname]{groupauthor}}}}}%
        \setunit{\ifbool{cbx:np}
                  {\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}
                  {\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}\addspace\bibopenparen}}%
        \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
          \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
           {}
           {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
             {}
             {\printnames{shortauthor}\setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}%
        \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}}
\makeatother
```

How should I modify the above to make \citet work? (\citep works)

Comment: \citep works though

Comment: don't show only snippets, always show a small but complete example so that we can test your issue.

Comment: If I combine the code you have shown so far into a simple example document I cannot reproduce the error: https://gist.github.com/moewew/2c6954ec63acd1dc3db8147f8789bc51. This suggests that something else is going on at your end. Presumably you have some additional code that causes the issue. Please post a compilable example document that reproduces the issue (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and linked posts).

Comment: I added more info @moewe

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out using another macro to link both author and year

Answer (score 1):

The additional code you have in your preamble to link more of the citation output is not compatible with the style you selected. (The code you have looks like it would work for - a possibly outdated version of - `biblatex-apa`.)

I would just accept that linked areas are a little smaller than with `natbib` and get on with it. But if you absolutely must have bigger link areas, then I would suggest you follow [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear (biblatex 1.4b)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864) for `style=authoryear,`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that to link both author and year in citation when using this biblatex style with natbib=true without error coming for even all other natbib citation commands including `\citet`, we can use the following bib macro I used from @lockstep [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/hyperlink-name-with-biblatex-authoryear)

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citep}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citep}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{ \usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcitetext}[\mkbibfootnotetext]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citet}
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{textcite}}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}%
   \multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
```